# Are automorphism groups of hypersurfaces reduced ?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, characteristic-p, algebraic-groups

In the following article : "H. Matsumura, P. Monsky, On the automorphisms of hypersurfaces, J. Math. Kyoto Univ. 3 (1964) 347-361", it is shown that in finite characteristic, automorphism groups of smooth hypersurfaces of $\mathbb{P}^N$ are finite (with known exceptions such as quadrics, elliptic curves, K3 surfaces). However, the question of their reducedness is left open. Does anyone know something about it ?

In fact, we need to show that $H^0(X,T_X)=0$. In characteristic $0$, you can use Bott's theorem to do that. What can you do in finite characteristic ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "known exceptions"?  So far as I know, a necessary and sufficient condition for the automorphism group of every smooth degree $d$ hypersurface in $\mathbb{P}^N$ [over a fixed, say, algebraically closed field] to be finite is $d > N+1$, equivalently for the variety to be of general type.  I also thought that it was a general theorem that varieties of general type had finite automorphism group: is this harder to prove in characteristic $p$?  (Is it false?!?)

Comment: The projective automorphism group of a hypersurface is finite, except for quadrics. The whole automorphism group coincides with the projective one except in the cases mentioned by Olivier. But this happens for different reasons if $N>2,d\neq N+1$ and if $N>3$. Namely, if $N>2$, then we can use the fact that the Picard is torsion free and the canonical class is $n+1$ times the hyperplane section. If $N>3$, then the Picard is $\mathbf{Z}$ and the effective cone is spanned by the hyperplane section.

Comment: Olivier -- I'm not 100% sure, but you could try cubic curves over a field of characteristic 3 to get a non-reduced example. But in any characteristic the projective automorphism groups are finite.

Comment: @Pete : It is true that varieties of general type have finite automorphism groups, but the converse is not (think of a blow-up of the plane in more than four points !). And for hypersurfaces, this happens most of the time (example : cubic surfaces which are blow-ups of the plane in six points). However, as long as I know, varietes of general type could very well have nonreduced automorphism groups (?). I don't have any example at hand.



Comment: @Algori : I don't think it will work : for an elliptic curve, $T_X$ is trivial, so the automorphism group has tangent space of dimension $1$ at the identity. Hence the (connected component of the) automorphism group has to be the reduced elliptic curve itself.

Comment: @Pete: No, the sufficient condition is $d\ge3$, see e.g. Mumford GIT 4.2, where the reference is to a Kodaira-Spencer's paper (which I am guessing is not helpful for char p).

Comment: @VA: I must not be understanding you correctly, since elliptic curves have infinite automorphism group, and I believe that there are Calabi-Yau hypersurfaces of every dimension with infinite automorphism group.  Do you perhaps mean projective automorphisms?  (I didn't.)  

Comment: @VA: Okay, I checked -- you are talking about projective automorphisms.  If I recall correctly, the point is that the condition $d > N+1$ forces all automorphisms to be projective, and I think this is true regardless of characteristic.  To clarify my original comment: I suppose things like Calabi-Yaus of arbitrary dimension fall under "known exceptions".

Comment: Pete -- Calabi-Yau hypersurfaces of dimension 3 or more have finite automorphism groups, see my comment above. Moreover, all their automorphisms are projective.

Comment: @Pete: I should have said if $d\ge3$ + $X$ is NOT an elliptic curve then there are no infinitesimal automorphisms (projective or not). And if $\dim X\ge3$ then $Pic X=Z$, so all automorphisms are projective (since $O(1)$ goes to itself).

Comment: @algori : In fact, we were both right : the automorphism group of elliptic curves in char $3$ is reduced, but their projective automorphism group isn't.  It is well explained in the book of Katz and Sarnak to which Bjorn Poonen refers in his answer.

Comment: Olivier -- yes, I was thinking about the projective automorphism groups. Thanks for mentioning this, I definitely have to take a look in that book.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If $X$ is a smooth hypersurface in $\mathbf{P}^{n+1}$ of degree $d$, where $n \ge 1$, $d \ge 3$, and $(n,d) \ne (1,3)$, then $H^0(X,T_X)=0$ by Theorem 11.5.2 in Katz and Sarnak, *Random matrices, Frobenius eigenvalues, and monodromy*, AMS Colloquium Publications, vol. 45, 1999.  So the connected component of the identity of the automorphism group scheme is trivial in these cases.  See also Theorem 11.1 in http://www-math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/projaut.pdf ,
which is Poonen, Varieties without extra automorphisms III: hypersurfaces, *Finite fields and their applications* **11** (2005), 230-268.