# Is there a way to compute explicitly global sections of tangent sheaf to a projective hypersurface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f\in \mathbb{C}[z_{0},\ldots,z_{n}]$ be an irreducible homogeneous polynomial and $X=V(f)\subset\mathbb{P}^{n}$ the projective hypesurface associated. I want to find (if any) explicit generators of $H^{0}(X,T_{X})$, at least their expression in the affine charts $U_{i}$. For example when $i=0$ i set 
$$x_{k}=\frac{z_{k}}{z_{0}}$$ 
and i'd like to find a tangent vector field to $X$ in the form
$$\xi=\sum_{k=1}^{n}q_{k}(x_1,\ldots, x_{n})\partial_{k}$$
with $q_{k}$ rational functions. Is this problem solvable? Is there a computer program that can give me this result?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If $X$ is smooth, there is no non-trivial vector fields unless $X$ is a quadric or a plane cubic : see for instance http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10743/are-automorphism-groups-of-hypersurfaces-reduced .

Comment: I allow $X$ to be normal with isolated singular points